# Ionic CLI not generating release build for Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

When I use the command: `cordova build --release android` the CLI throws the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'minimatch'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sologic\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\glob\glob.js:44:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
```

But when I use Ionic Lab (Windows Installer) and using the `Build` option - it generates '`android-debug.apk`' & '`android-debug-unaligned.apk`' in the `android\build\outputs\apk` folder.

Note that it is not generating `android-release-unsigned.apk`

My questions are:

1: What is wrong with the CLI ??

2: can I use the `android-debug-unaligned.apk` for Signing (with `jarsigner`) and Aligning (with `zipalign` ) for submitting on Google Play ??

Please advice.

Answer (score 3):

1. Nothing went wrong with IONIC CLI at this time (v1.7.6), because I'm using it every day.

   - Check your CLI version by this command `ionic --version` and see if your version is lower than `1.7.6`.
   - If your CLI is old, run `npm install -g ionic` again to install the lasted version of Ionic CLI.
   - If not, try to re-create all new project, and try to build again with, if it OK, just because of your project:

     - `ionic start appName blank`
     - `ionic platform add android`
     - `ionic build android --release`
2. You can't use the debug apk for Google Play because they can read your APK and check if is is debug or release version. But I think you can set the `debug mode` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` to false and try like this:

   - Add `android:debuggable="false"` to the `<application>` element.
   - More info : [Using Hardware Devices](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html).
3. Ionic also provide a **package** cloud service very helpful for non-plugin project inside the Ionic CLI. It can build all your project in the cloud in a minute and you can download the apk anytime.

   - cd to your ionic project folder by Ionic CLI.
   - Run `ionic package build android` an wait for the progress to done.
   - Run `ionic package list` to get the list and see the status if it has been done the building progress.
   - Run `ionic package download [id]` to download your apk to your project folder. `id` is the number you see in the `list`.
   - These commands will help you build the debug apk, for the release version, check this [ionic.io package documents](http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/package-android) to build with `profile` (keystore).

Comment: Thanks Nam for taking time and answering my questions.   

I however, copied the project folder to another machine (this time on a 64 bit Windows 7) and ran the cordova build --release android command and it perfectly generated the 'android-release-unsigned.apk'

What could be the reason to this ?

Comment: Did it helpful for you?

Comment: Hi Nam ... thanks again. .. I did not create a new project and test as you mentioned. Instead - I copied the entire Project Folder to my home system (this time on a 64 bit Windows 7) .. Removed the 'build' folder from '..\platforms\android' directory ... and then ran the 'cordova build --release android' command ... it generated the release build smoothly. Not sure why it did not work at my office PC ?? Any idea ?? ..... has it something to do with Cordova ! (node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\glob\glob.js:44:17 )  ???

Comment: Hmm this may be because of the current CLI in your office PC or missing some node modules, that why I think it should be create a new project and test it on your office PC to detect real problem.
If because of CLI it ok to re-install again, otherwise your project maybe missing somethings, copy all source code inside `www` folder to new project may solve that.

Comment: Ok.. Great .. will reach office soon .. and test it .. and I will let you know in next 2 hrs. Thanks Nam .. and yes .. here is another issue I posted on Ionic Forum regarding CLI Installation:  http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/failed-to-install-latest-cli/34690?u=digitaliq  ..

Comment: Hi Nam.. the android platform could not be added : I am creating a new question here at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384345/ionic-cli-could-not-add-platform-android .. Please review ..